# Where is pr2_kinect_empty_world.launch on fuerte?

Tags: ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can run this on electric:

```
  roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_kinect_empty_world.launch
```

How to run it on ros fuerte?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42092/where-is-pr2_kinect_empty_world.launch-on-fuerte?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the default pr2 now comes with kinect, so

```
roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_empty_world.launch
```

should start pr2 with kinect.  Is that what you needed?

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0